# Orientation always result to portrait (Motion Controls in libgdx)

Tags: java, android, libgdx, orientation

My code is as follows:

```
Input.Orientation orientation = Gdx.input.getNativeOrientation();
message = "";
switch (orientation) {
    case Landscape:
        message += "Landscape\n";
        break;
    case Portrait:
        message += "Portrait\n";
        break;
    default:
        message += "Whatever\n";
}
```

The above code(inside render method) always indicates that the device is in portrait mode, even when i rotate the device! What am I doing wrong? How can I accurately detect whether the device is in Portrait or Landscape mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getNativeOrientation()` doesn't return current orientation of device, it is returning something like whether the screen is landscape or portrait when you hold it properly (on most phones it should return portrait, but I guess on tablets and phones like HTC ChaCha it returns landscape).

There are several ways to get current orientation:

- **Recommended:** Use `Gdx.input.getRotation()` which returns rotation of device in degrees (0, 90, 180, 270) with respect to its native orientation. Use it with `getNativeOrientation()` and you should be able to get right orientation for all devices.

Note: it gives you orientation of current state of application, not orientation of device as physical object. So if you have a `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in your manifest, this method will always return landscape.

Example usage:

```
int rotation = Gdx.input.getRotation();
if((Gdx.input.getNativeOrientation() == Input.Orientation.Portrait && (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)) || //First case, the normal phone
        (Gdx.input.getNativeOrientation() == Input.Orientation.Landscape && (rotation == 0 || rotation == 180))) //Second case, the landscape device
    Gdx.app.log("Orientation", "We are in landscape!");
else
    Gdx.app.log("Orientation", "We are in portrait");
```

- Create interface on native side (Android), pass it to game.
- If you are using this as controls maybe you should use [accelerometer](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Accelerometer) or [gyroscope](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gyroscope) instead